# how to get the value into directive from controller using scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I define a controller and directive in app.js and use it in index.html.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});
app.directive('search', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            display: '='
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            alert(display);
        }
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <search display="name"></search>
</body>
</html>
```

When I give alert(display) in my directive it should print "world".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `scope.display`:

```
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
       alert(scope.display);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you create a plunker that demonstrates the issue

Comment: The error is: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template.html. If you load the non-minified version of angular, the error messages make more sense.